# count the numbers of words of a file in another file

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 text files. The first one contains 1000 words, each in a new line. The second contains a lot of sentences. I have to find the count of each word of the first file in the second file and write the result in a new file. (I have to use this result file for another piece of code). This code doesn't print anything and the output file contains just some letters. I hope somebody can fix it.

```
from collections import Counter

file=open("c:/python34/tes.txt", encoding="utf-8")
f1=file.read().split()
file2=open("c:/python34/new.txt", encoding="utf-8")
f2=file2.read().split()
c = Counter()
for word in f1:
    for w in f2:
        if word==w:
            c[word] += 1
            print(c)

f3=open("c:/python34/result.txt", "w")
f3.write(str(c))
f3.write(" ")
```

It works well for English. But my files language is persian.

A part of tes file:

است 
گفت 
كرد 
طرح 
سال 
مي‌شود 
سياسي 
تهران 
ادامه 
ايران 
وجود 
انجام

A part of new file:

دانشگاه خبرگزاري دانشجويان ايران ، دانشگاه ايده‌

Comment: Please post sample text files, so we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the behavior you describe.  Editing your sample date into the code to produce an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as you should have done (and with output changed)

```
from collections import Counter

f1 = '.است گفت كرد طرح سال مي‌شود سياسي تهران ادامه ايران وجود انجام'.split()
f2 ='دانشگاه خبرگزاري دانشجويان ايران ، دانشگاه ايده‌'.split()
c = Counter()
for word in f1:
    for w in f2:
        if word==w:
            c[word] += 1
            print(w)
print(c)
```

prints

```
ايران
Counter({'ايران': 1})
```

EDIT: I copied/pasted the output above, but it looks wrong, perhaps because of the right-to-left nature of Arabic.  This could use more investigation.

Comment: Thanks. I had to move the place of writing of print(c). Now it works.

Comment: but how about if I want to display the number 0 for the words which aren't in the second file. something like this: Counter({'ايران': 1, است: 0, انجام: 0, وجود: 0, ...})

Comment: Counter is a subclass of dict.  Iterate through the list of targets (f1 in the example) and lookup each with counter.get(item,  0) to default to 0 for items not in counter.